# Update function in magento 2 is not working

Tags: php, magento2

I want to update status of an entry in my database. I tried to execute an update query, but it throws `HTTP ERROR 500` error. The project is done in magento 2. Here is my code.

```
namespace Bridge\Batchcode\Controller\Adminhtml\Items;
use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Delete extends \Bridge\Batchcode\Controller\Adminhtml\Items{

public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($id) {
        try {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Bridge\Batchcode\Model\Items');
            $model->load($id);
            $productid = $model->getProductId();
            $prev_qty = $model->getBatchQty();


            $bind       = ['status' => 'Inactive'];
            $where      = ['id = ?' => (int)$id] ];
            $tableName  = $this->getConnection()->getTableName("batchcode_entity");

            $this->getConnection()->update($tableName, $bind, $where);

                $objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $stockRegistry  = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
                $product        = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
                $stockitem      = $stockRegistry->getStockItem(
                                                            $product->getId(),
                                                            $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
                                                            );

            if ( ($stockitem->getId() > 0) && ($stockitem->getManageStock())) {
                $qty     = $stockitem->getQty();
                $qty_new = $qty-$prev_qty;
                $stockitem->setQty($qty_new);
                $stockitem->save();
            }

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You deleted the item.'));
            $this->_redirect('bridge_batchcode/*/');
            return;

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t delete item right now. Please review the log and try again.')
            );
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            $this->_redirect('bridge_batchcode/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t find a item to delete.'));
    $this->_redirect('bridge_batchcode/*/');
  }
}
```

I am not sure, if I am missing something, because I am new to magento. Can I execute custom query in magento? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the way you use $this->getConnection().
It is a method but I cannot see where you define it.
You need to add this `\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,` to your constructor and then create getConnection().

```
 protected $connection;

 public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,

        Context $context,
        public function __construct(
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

  protected function getConnection()
  {
     if (!$this->connection) {
         $this->connection = $this->_resource->getConnection('core_write');
     }
     return $this->connection;
  }
```